# textbook for self studying geometry

Tags: geometry, self-learning, book-recommendation

Looking for recommended readings in geometry for self study. I am planning to get this book for self study.

[Geometry: A High School Course](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387966544)

Comment: That one looks pretty good.  Serge Lang was a great mathematician.  Why are you looking for other books?  Is there some specific geometric idea that Lang's book doesn't cover that you'd like to learn?

Comment: i did not read the Lang's book. I was planning to get a used copy of the book presuming it was good.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that you said that you're planning to get it.  I assumed you perused the table of contents though.  And I just wondered why you're looking to get another book when you haven't even started this one yet.  People will often advise that you should read multiple books on a subject at once to fill in the gaps or something, but IMO one should just focus on a single book at a time.  If it turns out not to be a well-written/ useful book, then switch to something else.  I don't see the point in taking twice as long to learn something because you want a slightly deeper exposure.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the Green Lion edition of [Euclid's Elements](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1888009187). It's a beautiful text with a clever feature. Any proposition that covers two pages has the diagram repeated on the next page, so you don't interrupt your train of thought, flipping pages to and fro.

There's also an [interactive java version](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/elements.html).

Comment: Thank you, will read it after finishing lang's book